# How to set background-size to cover on a Preus theme in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my first time trying out wordpress and I can't seem to find a way to stop the header image form stretching. Preus theme, which I'm using, doesn't seem to have a custom header option. I do understand the HTML/CSS syntax though I'm not sure where nor how to implement it. From my understanding a simple

```
header{
background-size: contain;
}
```

that I am adding in appearance>customize>additional css should be enough, though it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what am I messing up?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a specificity issue. Have you tried adding !important to override potential styling from the theme that has higher specificity?

Comment: Did try, nothing changed.